# Problems with upgrading to org-mode 9 and org repository

Tags: org-mode, package-repositories, upgrade

I have Emacs 25.1 (9.0) on macOS Sierra from Homebrew and <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `org-version` shows version 8.2.10. On org-mode official website, I've seen that the latest version is 9.0. It's not that I'd use any of the newest features, but it bothers me that Emacs won't update. I have the following lines in my `init.el`:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t) 
(package-initialize)
```

Running <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `package-list-packages` *seems* to at least connect to repositories and fetch some metadata (there is some activity on the mode-line and apparently no error is returned). Pressing <kbd>U</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> says it has no packages to update and the curious thing is that while I see packages from `melpa` and `gnu`, there's nothing from `org` repository ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VicEs.png)). Why can't I update to org-mode 9.0 and why there's no package from `org` repo in my list?

On Windows 10 (Emacs 25.1.1), with the exact same [init.el](https://github.com/ctanas/emacs/blob/master/init.el) as on macOS, I have org-mode version 9.0.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I didn't had org-mode installed from repos, it was the built-in one from Emacs, thus it didn't update from repos. So, I selected it from the packages list by pressing <kbd>i</kbd>, installed it, and I now have the latest version on macOS too.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to close out this question.